# How do I load a layer transparency and save as a path in the Photoshop JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, api, save, transparency, photoshop

I'm very new to javascripting and am trying to process a load of layers in photoshop to output each layer's loaded selection as an ai path..

The problem I'm having is understanding the channel arg of selection.load.

In photoshop the drop down of load selection shows the channel name as "layer_7 Transparency". but passing this doesn't seem to work.

```
 for(a=2;a<=AD.layers.length;a++){
    AD.layers[a-2].visible = 0;
    AD.layers[a-1].visible = 1;


    if((checkArray[a-1]!= 1)&&(checkArray[a-1]!= 2)){ 

        var channel = AD.channels.getByName(AD.layers[a-1].name+" Transparency");
        AD.selection.load(channel, SelectionType.REPLACE, false);

        AD.selection.makeWorkPath(1.0)

        newAIFile = new File(tempFolder+"/"+AD.layers[a-1].name+".ai");
        AD.exportDocument(newaiFile , ExportType.ILLUSTRATORPATHS , exportOptions)




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In scripting, the first layer in the collection is the one that is added last.  It is at index 0 in the `Document.artLayers` collection.

```
// Get a reference to the first layer in the document
var layerRef:Layer = app.activeDocument.layers.index(0);

// Get a reference to a layer by name
var baseLayer:Layer = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("Background");
```

Because layer sets can be nested, you may have to drill down through contained layer sets to reach a particular layer or layer set:

```
app.activeDocument.layerSets.index(0).layerSets.index(0);
```

**References**

- [Scripting Photoshop: Working with Layers](http://cssdk.host.adobe.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/app_notes/ps_doc_model.htm#Working_with_layers)